# For window 8.1 in my laptop keyboard constantly pressing the ESC?

Tags: keyboard, escape-characters

For window 8.1 in my laptop  keyboard  constantly pressing the ESC? 
At time of writing or even in playing games. Even now I can't type, repeatedly ESC is being pressed automatically.

I have tried updating my laptop but still no hope.

Comment: This can even be a hardware related issue. Isn't the key stuck? Try to move / clean it.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the escape key has got stuck or there is a foreign body under it which is bridging the contacts. Have you spilled a drink on it?

You can try one of the following:

- Use an [air duster](http://www.poundland.co.uk/air-duster) to blow the dirt away from your keys
- Shake the laptop upside-down while the lid is open (make sure the laptop is off for this one)
- Try prising the key off with the end of a spoon or screwdriver, it will clip back on afterwards. While the key is off you can try a *damp* cloth on the rubbery underlay to remove dried sugar residue or dirt.

If none of the above works the actual keyboard might be broken. In which case you will need to replace it, for most laptops these clip out and can be easily replaced by the consumer. You will have to check on eBay for your specific make and model. If you aren't comfortable with doing it yourself most local PC repair shops will do it for you for a small fee.